# how to make getArray method

Tags: arrays

When I run a specific part of a code I have:

```
 public String getWords (){
    randomWord = words[randy.nextInt(words.length)];
    return randomWord;
}

private String[] words = {"apple", "beret", "arose", "along", "beamy", "becks", "decks", "barks",
                              "stark", "start", "stabs", "baggy", "asked", "asset", "asses", "audit",
                              "bowls", "boxes", "seats", "balls", "boats", "boxer", "brick", "bound",
                              "brass", "caked", "braid", "caged", "essay", "fault", "dents", "dutch",
                              "ethos", "dunks", "pains", "faxes", "mummy", "mixer", "mills", "might",
                              "moral", "teeth", "wings", "works", "walls", "tolls", "crawl", "toxin",
                              "bangs", "tough"};


Hangman man = new Hangman();
      man.mainScreen();



public void mainScreen (){
        start();
        while (guesses != maxGuesses){
            continueGame();
            checkBodyParts();
        }
        gameOver();
    }
```

ERROR:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Hangman.getWords(Hangman.java:43)
at Hangman.<init>(Hangman.java:28)
at GameApp.main(GameApp.java:9)
```

I get a runtime error of NullPointerException. I asked around and they said I should make a method to get the array words because I can't get to it at the moment. What should this method have in it?

Comment: You should tag this in the language you're using.

Comment: Post exact error message or stack trace.

Comment: My best guess is that either randomWord or randy have not been instantiated. Can you post your init and main methods?

Comment: Okay, that doesn't exactly clear things up either. What I was looking for was some sort of object creation of "randy". Do you have anywhere in your code "[object name] randy = new [object name]()". If not, that's what you need to add.

Comment: I have this. Random randy = new Random(); if that does anything at all.

Comment: That creates your object. As long as that is called some time before getWords() is ever called then I was wrong and it's not the issue.

Comment: Yea, it's the first thing that I have that is initialized.

Comment: Try doing this: String randomWord = ""; When you create your "randomWord" variable.

Comment: Okay, I understand you're probably frustrated at this point. I'd really like to know what's going on here, too. Something is missing that isn't making sense here. If you're in Eclipse, do you have any variables underlined in yellow? If you have something like this: "
private Random randy;" as an instance variable, then you declare it somewhere else as "Random randy = new Random();" then you just made two different variables. It's possible something like this is going on. Could you please add more of your code so I can try to help you more?

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse, I wish I was. You can read what others are posting here: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/67820-null-pointer-exception.html#post318797 . last time I posted my full code the question was blocked.

Comment: Can you confirm the language? This is Java, right?

Comment: I think you need to post a fuller code example. We're not getting a full enough picture.

Comment: @user1972601, did that answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is here:

```
private String myGeneratedRandomWord = getWords();
```

This method is trying to use the array "words" before it is created.
Move this line after the array "words" is created.

This should solve your NullPointerError.